# >Client side using pagination code show some error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

HI i m using javascript code for client side and my data is dynamic and first is page load if i click to a `button` than data loading .

i m finding this code in google and using to our projects but i have face one error if i click to `button` than show data and showing pagination after that i click to pagination number than show error in `console`,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: pager is not defined

My Code is

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.rohit').on('click',function(){
    alert('Rohit');

    function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;
    this.inited = false;
    
    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {        
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        // i starts from 1 to skip table header row
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to)  
                rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            else
                rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }
    
    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {
      if (! this.inited) {
        alert("not inited");
        return;
      }

        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';
        
        this.currentPage = pageNumber;
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';
        
        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
        this.showRecords(from, to);
    }   
    
    this.prev = function() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1)
            this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
    }
    
    this.next = function() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
            this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
        }
    }                        
    
    this.init = function() {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1); 
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
    }

    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {
      if (! this.inited) {
        alert("not inited");
        return;
      }
      var element = document.getElementById(positionId);
      
      var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> &#171 Prev </span> | ';
        for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++) 
            pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> | ';
        pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next &#187;</span>';            
        
        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
    }
};

var pager = new Pager('results', 3); 
        pager.init(); 
        pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition'); 
        pager.showPage(1);
   });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table-bordered" id="results">
                                              <thead>
                                                  <th>S.no</th>
                                              </thead>
                                              <tbody id="userData">
                                                  <tr><td>1</td></tr> <tr><td>2</td></tr> <tr><td>3</td></tr> <tr><td>4</td></tr> <tr><td>5</td></tr> 
                                              </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <div id="pageNavPosition"></div>

                                        <span class="rohit">Click to this </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the working code.**

```
function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;
    this.inited = false;

    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {        
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        // i starts from 1 to skip table header row
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to)  
                rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            else
                rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }

    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {
      if (! this.inited) {
        alert("not inited");
        return;
      }

        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';

        this.currentPage = pageNumber;
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';

        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
        this.showRecords(from, to);
    }   

    this.prev = function() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1)
            this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
    }

    this.next = function() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
            this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
        }
    }                        

    this.init = function() {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1); 
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
    }

    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {
      if (! this.inited) {
        alert("not inited");
        return;
      }
      var element = document.getElementById(positionId);

      var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> &#171 Prev </span> | ';
        for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++) 
            pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> | ';
        pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next &#187;</span>';            

        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
    }
};
var page;
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.rohit').on('click',function(){
    alert('Rohit');


 pager = new Pager('results', 3); 
        pager.init(); 
        pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition'); 
        pager.showPage(1);
   });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: pager is not defined

That's because its not.

You're defining the function in the callback of a click event:

```
 $('.rohit').on('click',function(){
    alert('Rohit');

    function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {
    ...
```

And trying to instantiate it on dom ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var pager = new Pager('results', 3); 
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `pager` is in local scope of `document ready`handler function.
And you're generating html with following code
`<span onclick="pager.next();"`.
In this case `pager` is being searched in global scope.

The easiest way to fix it - is to place pager in global scope by removing `var` before `pager` definition. But this is definetly not right solution.

Better one - subscribe on `click` events of your `prev` and `next` spans inside your `document ready` handler. It is easy with jQuery, and you're already using it.